# Counting how many dozen in a number and also count its extra amount?

Tags: c

How do i make this program counts how many dozen in a number and also count its extra amount?
This is what only I came up

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

float number, dozen;

printf("Please Enter any integer Value : ");

scanf("%f", &number);

dozen = number / 12;

printf("dozen of a given number %.2f is  =  %.2f", number, dozen);

return 0;

}
```

I dont know how i will get to count the dozen in a number, for example there is 45, i need to get 3 dozen and the extra will be 9.

Comment: why have you tagged `javascript` for a c/c++ issue

Comment: Please don't spam the tags, that only will earn you downvotes.

Comment: *"for example there is 45, i need to get 3 dozen and the extra will be 9."* -- this is your input and expected output. What is your actual output? In other words, why is your current program inadequate?

Comment: Hmmmm... How much would you get if you multiplied your `3` by `12`??? Does this suggest how to calculate the remainder??? (PS: The code asks for "an integer value", then accepts the user input into a float... Huh????)

Comment: im sorry i am a beginner

Comment: `"12 dozen"`??? That's just gross! `:-)` `:-)` `:-)` (I've waited **years** to use that old joke.)

Comment: it should be dozen, my prof wants dozen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prompt for an integer but then use floats.  You already had the correct dozen calculation and just miss the modulo operator `%`.  Reformatted code for readability.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Please Enter any integer Value : ");
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("dozen of a given number %d is %d with remainder %d\n",
        number,
        number / 12,
        number % 12
    );
    return 0;
}
```

and example execution:

```
Please Enter any integer Value : 14
dozen of a given number 14 is 1 with remainder 2
```

Comment: Implied by the fact you accepted the answer / upvote.  Make sure you read the comments, they will help get the most out of stackoverflow when you ask the next question.  Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Now that there is an accepted answer,
here's a small lesson in arithmetic (plagiarising @Allan Wind's answer):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Please Enter any integer Value : ");
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("dozen of a given number %d is %d with remainder %d\n",
        number,
        number / 12,
        number - ( number / 12 * 12)
    );
    return 0;
}
```